# Backend url is not formed when backend-id is used

Tags: azure-api-management

I want to connect to backend Url with backend-id.
Below is the policy I used. But url is not formed and got a repsonse "Backend service URL is not defined."

```
<inbound>
        <base />
        <set-backend-service backend-id="testbackend" />  
        <rewrite-uri template="/test" />
        <send-request mode="copy" response-variable-name="BackendResponse">
            <set-method>POST</set-method>
        </send-request>
</inbound>
```

When I removed send-request tag, the backend url is formed and the api call is success.
But I need to store the response in response-variable. So i have to use send-request. when this is used backend url is not formed.

```
<inbound>
        <base />
        <set-backend-service id="apim-generated-policy" backend-id="testbackend" />  
        <rewrite-uri template="/test" />
        <send-request mode="copy" response-variable-name="BackendResponse">
            <set-method>POST</set-method>
        </send-request>
</inbound>
```

Need to use backend-id instead if base-url as backend is an azure resource.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to connect to backend Url with backend-id. But url is not formed and got a response "Backend service URL is not defined."

You can use the below policy to store the response in response-variable.

```xml
<inbound>
    <base  />
    <set-backend-service  backend-id="testbackend"  />
    <rewrite-uri  template="/test"  />
</inbound>
<backend>
    <base  />
</backend>
<outbound>
    <base  />
    <send-request  mode="copy"  response-variable-name="BackendResponse">
        <set-method>POST</set-method>
    </send-request>
</outbound>
```

I am able to get the successful result.

[image]

[image]